# Gold Mine Problem - Sequence of for loops

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

[Gold mine problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gold-mine-problem/). Following sequence for loop is giving correct result.

```
//see link for other code
static int getMaxGold(int gold[][], int m, int n) {
//see link for other code

       for (int col = n-1; col >= 0; col--) {
            for (int row = 0; row < m; row++) {
                int right = (col == n-1) ? 0 : goldTable[row][col+1];
                int right_up = (row == 0 || col == n-1) ? 0 : goldTable[row-1][col+1];
                int right_down = (row == m-1 || col == n-1) ? 0 : goldTable[row+1][col+1];
                goldTable[row][col] = gold[row][col] + Math.max(right, Math.max(right_up, right_down));
            }
        }
}
//see link for other code
```

While other way round does not give the expected result. For example

```
for (int col = 0; col < n; col ++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < m; row++) {
    //same code to calculate right, rightUp and rightDown
    }
}
```

Any explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: https://medium.com/@digankate26/dynamic-programming-vs-greedy-method-for-solving-gold-mine-problem-ff7ae20f05d7
I hope this can help you understand why starting from the last column gives the correct result.

Comment: @ShubhamRaitka didn't understand it.

Comment: In the 2nd case, you should not use exactly the same code, but for example replace `col+1` by `col-1`. You must calculate the new amounts from the amounts already calculated

Comment: Please provide full running code for the example you claim fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store a whole matrix.

When you build the table, you just need to keep the last layer you processed.

In your recursion, there is diagonally right, or right, so the layer is a column because to compute the value of some cell, you need to know three values (on its right)

You conclude (as spotted by Damien already) that you start from the rightmost column, then to compute the value of every cells of the n-1 column, you only need to know the nth column (which you luckily computed already)

In below example. `m_ij` refers to `i`-th line, `j`-th column. (e.g `m_01 == 2, m_10 = 5`)

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 1 2 3
4 5 6 3
```

The last column is `{4,8,3,3}`
To compute the max value for `m_02` you need to choose between `4` and `8`

```
3 - 4
  \
    8
```

```
m_02 = 3 + 8 = 11
```

To compute the max value of `m_12` you need to choose between `4`, `8` and `3`

```
    4
  /
7 - 8
  \
    3
```

```
m_12 = 7 + 8 = 15
```

Skipping stuff

```
m_22 = 2 + 8 = 10
m_32 = 6 + 3 = 9
```

Now you know the max value for each square of the third column

```
1 2 11 .
5 6 15 .
9 1 10 .
4 5 9  .
```

You do the same for `m_10, m_11`, ...
idem

```
m_01 = 2 + max(11, 15) = 17
m_11 = 6 + 15
m_21 = 1 + 15
m_31 = 5 + 10
```

Left to process is thus

```
1 17
5 21
9 16
4 15
```

Then

```
1+21
5+21
9+21
4+16
```

And finally score = max(22, 26, 30, 20)

As you have noticed you **only** need to keep track of the last processed column. Not a whole table of computation. And the last processed column must start from the right and always be the rightmost one...

I don't think an implem is relevant to help you understand but in case

```js
const s = `
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 1 2 3
4 5 6 3`

const m = s.trim().split('\n').map(x => x.trim().split(' ').map(y => parseInt(y)))
let layer = [0, 0, 0, 0]
for (let j = 3; j >= 0; --j) {
  const nextLayer = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    nextLayer[i] = m[i][j] + Math.max(
      layer[i-1] || 0, // we default undefined value as 0 supposing s only holds positive coefficient
      layer[i],
      layer[i+1] || 0
    )
  }
  layer = nextLayer
}
console.log(Math.max(...layer))
```